# Build a controller from scratch

Tags: ros, microcontroller, teleoperation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody!

After making a "stable" URDF of the robot that I want to simulate and make some tests with it in Gazebo, I'm trying to **build a controller** for teleop with it. Searching in the web I only found manuals and references from the pr2_controller.

It is essential inherit and implement PR2 classes like *pr2_controller_manager, pr2_controller_interface*...? There is any generic driver base? Actuators are essential?

Can anyone put some order into this chaos and explain briefly the steps in this process?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9551/build-a-controller-from-scratch/) by [mbj](https://answers.ros.org/users/265/mbj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 197 on 2011-03-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Work your way through the pr2_mechanism tutorials.  They describe how to implement and run a custom controller.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism/Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [sglaser](https://answers.ros.org/users/46/sglaser/) with karma: 649 on 2011-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4